# how to make vncserver to listen on port 443

Tags: networking, vnc, tightvncserver

Greeting.

I try to make vncserver listen on port 443 which is the https port.
It does not work and it gives me this log file:

$vncPort = 443 + $displayNumber;

And the log file shows this error:

```
_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root
/home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup: 2: /home/ubuntu/.vnc/xstartup: def: not found

Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc


Wed Jul 27 21:46:44 2016
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      vncExtInit: unable to bind listening socket: Permission denied
              (13)
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory

** (gnome-settings-daemon:2832): WARNING **: Unable to initialize GTK+
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gnome-panel:2831): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: ip-10-0-0-76:0
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Window manager error: Unable to open X display ip-10-0-0-76:0
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:2834): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: ip-10-0-0-76:0
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

I try doing sudo but it still does not work:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-76:~$ sudo vncserver :0
vncserver: Wrong type or access mode of /home/ubuntu/.vnc.
```

Comment: Don't use `sudo` for running a vncserver.

Comment: How I can make vncserver listen to any port I want ???